# Bibtex unresolved references in a simple example mac OS lion

Tags: bibtex

I have been trying to get BibTeX working but am really struggling. I have spent all morning doing google searches and trying to use other people's examples with no luck.

I am using the latest version of Mac OS X (Lion), Emacs, and AUCTeX.

The problem is that every time I try to pdflatex my TeX file I get unresolved references and all the citations are [?]. I have my TeX file and my `bib` file in the same folder.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{who}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}

@ARTICLE{who,
  author = {who},
  year = {2008}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to run `bibtex` after a `pdflatex` run:

```
pdflatex file
bibtex file
pdflatex file
pdflatex file
```

Comment: There is also a "BibTeX" entry in the "Command" menu provided by AUCTeX that runs `bibtex` on the file corresponding to the current buffer.

Comment: Had same problem as OP, @Boris solved it! Thanks bro.

Comment: Thanks. The last run was key. AucTeX used to prompt me to run pdflatex again to get the references right but somehow it didn't do so this time and prompted me to directly `Read` the file, which confused me.